# Bind ProgressRing to mvvm

Tags: mvvm, uwp

I am downloading data from an api, and displaying that data in the view. As I wait I want to display a ProgressRing, but when I bind it dosen't work

1. Bind the ring to the cityData property, with a two way mode and update it when the property changes
2. Created a new property in the VM, that is true by default and it will turn false when I get the data back

XAML

```
<TextBox x:Name="currentLocation"
                 PlaceholderText="Please wait..."
                 IsReadOnly="True"
                 Margin="20"
                 Width="300"
                 Text="{Binding cityData,  Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<ListView RelativePanel.Below="currentLocation"
                  x:Name="ForecastList"
                  Margin="20"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding currentDay, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding dailyForecasts}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="10">
               <TextBlock x:Name="dateTB" Text="{Binding Date.DayOfWeek}" />
               <TextBlock x:Name="highTB" Text="{Binding Temperature.Maximum.Value, Converter={StaticResource cv}}" FontSize="10" />
               <TextBlock x:Name="lowTB" FontSize="10" Text="{Binding Temperature.Minimum.Value, Converter={StaticResource cv}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<ProgressRing x:Name="pRing" RelativePanel.Above="ForecastList" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWith="currentLocation" IsActive="{Binding ring, Mode=TwoWay}" RelativePanel.Below="currentLocation" />
```

VM

```
public class WeatherVM: INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
 public AccuWeather accuWeather { get; set; }    
 private string _cityData;
 public string cityData 
 {
  get { return _cityData; }
  set 
  { 
    if (value != _cityData) 
      {
       _cityData = value;
       onPropertyChanged("cityData");
       GetWeatherData();
      }
   }
 }

 private DailyForecast _currentDay;
 public DailyForecast currentDay 
 {
  get { return _currentDay; }
  set 
  {
   if (value != _currentDay) \
   {
    _currentDay = value;
    onPropertyChanged("currentDay");
   }
  }
 }
 public bool ring { get; set; } = true;
 public ObservableCollection<DailyForecast> dailyForecasts { get; set; }
 public WeatherVM() 
 {
  GetCuurentLocation();
  dailyForecasts = new ObservableCollection<DailyForecast>();
 }
 private async void GetCuurentLocation() {
   cityData = await BingLocator.GetCityData();
 }
public async void GetWeatherData() {
 var geoposition = await LocationManager.GetGeopositionAsync();
 var currentLocationKey = await WeatherAPI.GetCityDstaAsync(geoposition.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude, geoposition.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude);
 var weatherData = await WeatherAPI.GetWeatherAsync(currentLocationKey.Key);
    if (weatherData != null) {
      foreach (var item in weatherData.DailyForecasts) {
          dailyForecasts.Add(item);
      }
    }
 currentDay = dailyForecasts[0];
 ring = false;
 }
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 private void onPropertyChanged(string property) {
   PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
 }
} 
}
```

The progress ring appears when the app launch, and disappear when the data is returned

Comment: The code doesn't show that `ring` is ever changed and that this change is accompanied with `onPropertyChanged("ring")` call, which could be _the_ problem. There are inconsistencies in description and code, meaning there could be other issues, but this is the first thing I'd check.

Comment: What do you propose, the progress bar has its own value property, tha is true by default, so at least it has to show. I changed it to a full property and an OnpropertyChqnged and nothing

Comment: I just put the full property for the ring, with a default value of true, and it does not show https://pastebin.com/ree9WJ1C

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it seems to be a layout issue. First you put ListView below currentLocation, then set ProgressRing above ListView and below currentLocation, so the height of ProgressRing wil be zero. I'm not clear about your layout, you can try to only set `RelativePanel.Above="ForecastList"` for ProgressRing to see if it will appear.

Comment: I checked your code and found the **ProgressRingIsActive** property didn't exist in WeatherVM class. So if you bind the **ring** property to the ProgressRing, will the same issue occur?

Comment: sorry my mistake, its working know. I have a question MVVM is very used these days? I do I just use the code behind, and the xaml

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to use MVVM? You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-and-mvvm).

Comment: Well this Weather app, was developed using MVVM, I just wanted to know if is used often

Comment: MVVM is just a design pattern. UWP supports this design pattern, but it is feasible to use any method of development. It is not necessary to use MVVM.

Comment: Could you help me with my code? I have 2 problems: I am trying to use MVVM but because I have an RichEditBox, I am doing the best I can. The oder problem is that I cant change the fontsize of the richeditbox https://pastebin.com/FxRbbfTW

Comment: By the way I finished the other one, I am a very fan of Microsoft and uwp, and I am planing to launch this simple note taking app to the store

Comment: Hi, about the problem of RichEditBox, you can open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Community Toolkit control for showing progress ring (Busy indicator).

```
<Page ...
     xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"/>

<controls:Loading x:Name="LoadingControl" IsLoading="{Binding IsBusy}">
    <!-- Loading screen content -->
</controls:Loading>
```